# Chrome zoom level at 25% breaks some parts of page

Tags: html, css

First things first, I've read other similar posts. nothing helped.

I have a pixel perfect website, without any percentages or so. when I zoom out it works just fine in Firefox and Edge, but in chrome, when it reaches to 25 percent, items don't fit in their parent.

```
    <div id="main_core_content">
        <div class="box_container">
            <div class="box_container_content">
```

Inside the last div(*box_container_content*), I've got list(li) of items in three columns (floated properly). so what I mean by no fitting is that for example, when you reach 25% zoom, floated items stay at their place, but list of item overflow from bottom. I've done many things, setting width, max-height and so on but no result at the end. by the way, the pop up modal window is absolutely positioned.

A simpler code:

```css
#main {
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  background: #9b9672;
  color: white;
  padding: 50px 20px 20px 20px;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="dicts1">
      <ul>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
        <li>Beer</li>
        <li>Cider</li>
        <li>Distilled (liquor)</li>
        <li>Hard soda</li>
        <li>Wine</li>
        <li>Barley</li>
        <li>Hot drinks</li>
        <li>Mixed drinks</li>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
        <li>Beer</li>
        <li>Cider</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
        <li>Beer</li>
        <li>Cider</li>
        <li>Distilled (liquor)</li>
        <li>Hard soda</li>
        <li>Wine</li>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
        <li>Beer</li>
        <li>Cider</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried or considered bootstrap? It's generally a good choice for keeping things aligned and the right size while changing zoom. Or could you post your whole code?

Comment: @JoelBanks edited the post

Answer (score 0):

Chrome seems to still have problems with absolute units. While all major browsers recalculate absolute units to fit the page content with the zoom level, it looks like some still do a bad job. (I was only able to test all major browsers on a Mac right now - Opera has the same bug ... which shouldn't be of any surprise as it's using almost the same rendering engine)

It is always wise to use relative units over absolute ones as much as possible. Mentioned quite often (e.g. [here](https://css-tricks.com/zooming-squishes/) and [here](https://engageinteractive.co.uk/blog/em-vs-rem-vs-px)).
In short, `em` is better for accessibility as there are less problems with zoom levels.

You can also see how using `em` fixes your example as well:

```css
#main {
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  background: #9b9672;
  color: white;
  padding: 50px 20px 20px 20px;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

ul {
  margin-left: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

/* absolute values which still would break
ul {
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
*/
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="dicts1">
      <ul>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
        <li>Beer</li>
        <li>Cider</li>
        <li>Distilled (liquor)</li>
        <li>Hard soda</li>
        <li>Wine</li>
        <li>Barley</li>
        <li>Hot drinks</li>
        <li>Mixed drinks</li>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
        <li>Beer</li>
        <li>Cider</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
        <li>Beer</li>
        <li>Cider</li>
        <li>Distilled (liquor)</li>
        <li>Hard soda</li>
        <li>Wine</li>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
        <li>Beer</li>
        <li>Cider</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: actually, I don't think it's a bug! I had lots of issues in chrome that when I re managed them, (logically) everything looked good. The problem is that, when something doesn't fit inside it's parent, there should be overflow, but not with zooming in, things should shrink down accordingly. why is that? even though they aren't absolute